# Webpack 3.10.0 and babel-polyfill issue at runtime

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, webpack-3, babel-polyfill

I'm currently using Webpack 3.10.0 along with following babel packages.

```
"babel": "^6.23.0",
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "~6.13.2",
"babel-preset-react": "~6.11.1",
```

My issue is, during runtime I get the following error on the browser console and the page doesn't load.

```
bundle.js:737 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "babel-polyfill"
    at webpackMissingModule (bundle.js:737)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:737)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:679)
    at bundle.js:725
    at bundle.js:728
```

My webpack.config.js looks as below.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: {
        bundle: ['babel-polyfill', './Main.js'],
        bundleIntegrated: ['babel-polyfill', './MainInt.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/myproject')
    },
    target: 'web',
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 3000,
        proxy: {
            '/myct/**': {
                target: 'http://localhost:9000',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            config: path.join(__dirname, 'config/config.dev')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
                {
                    test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
                    enforce: 'pre',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                            {
                                loader: "eslint-loader",
                            }
                        ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|__tests__)/,
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                            "style-loader",
                            "css-loader",
                        ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    use: [
                            "style-loader",
                            "css-loader",
                            "less-loader",
                        ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
                    use: [
                            {
                                loader: "file-loader?name=../assets/mastering/fonts/[name].[ext]",
                            },
                        ],
                },
        ],
    }
}
```

I have imported babel-polyfill into Main.js and MainInt.js files as instructed in https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/ and I haven't used `new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin()`.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You don't need to do both things. If you placed 'babel-polyfill' in webpack configuration, don't import/require it on Main/MainInt.js

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution. But it didn't work. I still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Thank you everyone for your help.

Giving the full path in filename fixed the issue.

```
 output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/myproject'),
        filename: '../assets/myproject/[name].js',
    },
```